# PostgreSQL Exception : syntax error

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use PostgreSQL with a java code in order to create a web service, but I keep having the same error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "CA8E6"
    Position : 84
```

Here is the function calling the query:

```
public ArrayList<Position> TrajectoireH(String icao, String date_deb, String date_fin)  {
    query = "SELECT reception_date,longitude,latitude"
            + " FROM adsb_message"
            + " WHERE mode_s_icao_id = " + icao
            + " AND reception_date > " + date_deb
            + " AND reception_date < " + date_fin;
    System.out.println(query);

    Avion av = new Avion(icao);

    Statement state;
    try {
        state = PostgreSQLConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet result = state.executeQuery(query);

        while(result.next()) {
            float lat,lon;
            String date;
            lat = result.getFloat("latitude");
            lon = result.getFloat("longitude");
            date = result.getString("reception_date");

            Position pos = new Position(lat,lon,date);
            av.ajoutPos(pos);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = result.getMetaData();


    return av.getTrajectoireH();
}
```

To run a test, I chose the ICAO "4CA8E6". It seems like the program stopped reading the ICAO at the first character. Printing the query returns:

```
SELECT reception_date,longitude,latitude FROM adsb_message 
    WHERE mode_s_icao_id = 4CA8E6 
        AND reception_date > 2000-01-01 00:00:00.0
        AND reception_date < 3000-01-01 00:00:00.0
```

This seems correct to me. Do you know where the syntax error could come from?

Comment: Don't concatenate input values into the SQL string. Use a `PreparedStatement` for security reasons and as a nice side effects your problem will also go away

Comment: If you think that `mode_s_icao_id = 4CA8E6` or `reception_date > 2000-01-01 00:00:00.0` are valid SQL expression, then run that in the SQL client of your choice. You might also want to read the manual on how to properly specify constant values in a query: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: As already pointed out. The printed query is NOT a valid SQL.

Comment: As addendum to @a_horse_with_no_name comments: You shouldn't use strings for dates. It's better to use `java.sql.Date` for parameters in prepared statements. The driver should format the date according to the underlying DBMS.

Comment: The reception_date column is of type "timestamp with time zone". Would the function Timestamp.valueOf(date_deb) coupled with a setTimestamp be a good solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of your error is obvious, since the raw query has unescaped string and date literals in it.  The best fix is to use prepared statements, as I have shown below.  Note that I bound the variables `date_feb` and `date_fin` as strings, when in fact best practice would be to bind some sort of compatible Java date type (e.g. `java.util.Date` or maybe something from the Java 8 API).  Binding string literals might work if your database accepts it.  I haven't corrected this because most likely you have date variables somewhere in your Java code already, and you just need to start using them.

```
String query = "SELECT reception_date,longitude,latitude"
             + " FROM adsb_message"
             + " WHERE mode_s_icao_id = ?"
             + " AND reception_date > ?"
             + " AND reception_date < ?";
PreparedStatement ps = PostgreSQLConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, icao);
ps.setString(2, date_feb);
ps.setString(3, date_fin);
ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

while (result.next()) {
    float lat, lon;
    String date;
    lat = result.getFloat("latitude");
    lon = result.getFloat("longitude");
    date = result.getString("reception_date");

    Position pos = new Position(lat,lon,date);
    av.ajoutPos(pos);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
    reception_date,
    longitude,
    latitude 
FROM adsb_message 
WHERE 
    mode_s_icao_id = '4CA8E6' 
    AND reception_date > '2000-01-01 00:00:00.0' 
    AND reception_date < '3000-01-01 00:00:00.0'
```

Comment: While this does fix the raw query, it does not help with how to prevent it from happening in the Java code (not my downvote).

Comment: You just have to add apostrophes in the query string.

Comment: Yes, you are correct but the query is being generated from Java, so your answer should ideally say something about the code problem as well.

Comment: I do not understand, you write that it crashes you, so I wrote you how to get the query to look like, what it boils down to adding the apostrophes in the "query" string.

Comment: String query = "SELECT reception_date,longitude,latitude FROM adsb_message WHERE mode_s_icao_id = '" + icao
            + "' AND reception_date > '" + date_deb
            + "' AND reception_date < '" + date_fin + "'";